# wx python BoxSizer not expanding to window plus an odd blank gap at top of GUI

Tags: python, wxwidgets, boxsizer

I am having some issues properly expanding my sizers.  I have added two sub panels which I was hoping would solve my issue, but it seems to have made it worse.  What I am hoping to do is have `top_panel` expand to the extents of the width of the main `panel`.  `vbox_top_right` should expand to fill the rest of `hbox_top`.  The `bottom_panel` should then expand both horizontally and vertically to fill in the rest of the space of the main `panel`.  None of this is happening.

Once I split everything up into two sub panels, I am now having an issues where I have a large blank space up top.  Also, my `bottom_panel` does not seem to be expanding anywhere.  I am also not sure if I am using `SetSizerAndFit` correctly because I haven't seen anywhere mentioning the use of it on multiple panels.  Am I only supposed to be applying it to the main `panel`?

Note that I am forcing use of wx 3.0.  I have 2.8 and 3.0 installed and had issues with wx.StaticBoxSizer with 2.8.  I know this likely has nothing to do with my issue, just the code won't work correctly if you are trying it in 2.8.

CODE:

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select('3.0')
import wx
import os
import sys


VERSION = '1.0.0'


class GUI(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=title, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                          size=wx.Size(1280, 768), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu = wx.Menu()
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()

        # Quit code
        file_item = file_menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit', 'Quit Application')
        menu_bar.Append(file_menu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)

        # Add Main panel
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # Add Top and Bottom Panels
        self.top_panel = wx.Panel(self.panel)
        self.bottom_panel = wx.Panel(self.panel)


        # Create horizontal and vertical boxes
        self.hbox_main = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vbox_main = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.hbox_top = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vbox_top_left = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox_top_right = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        ####################################################
        # TOP
        ####################################################

        ##########################
        # TOP LEFT
        ##########################
        # List box text
        self.lbl_filter = wx.StaticText(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY,
                                        u"Select all cases to apply file to",
                                        wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.lbl_filter.Wrap(-1)
        self.vbox_top_left.Add(self.lbl_filter, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        # The list box that all the file names are in
        self.list_box = wx.CheckListBox(self.top_panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(300, 300),
                                        choices=[], style=wx.LB_HSCROLL|wx.LB_MULTIPLE|wx.LB_NEEDED_SB|wx.LB_SORT)
        self.vbox_top_left.Add(self.list_box, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # List box filter text
        self.lbl_filter = wx.StaticText(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY,
                                        u"Case filter (separate wildcards with a comma and choose filter logic (AND or OR)\n(i.e. HS, 2022 with AND selected will modify all 2022 HS cases)",
                                        wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.lbl_filter.Wrap(-1)
        self.vbox_top_left.Add(self.lbl_filter, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        # List box filter
        self.hbox_filter = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.txt_filter = wx.TextCtrl(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.txt_filter.SetMinSize(wx.Size(300, -1))
        self.hbox_filter.Add(self.txt_filter, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # List box radio buttons
        logic_choices = [u"AND", u"OR"]
        self.rdo_logic = wx.RadioBox(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Filter Logic", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                                     logic_choices, 1, wx.RA_SPECIFY_ROWS)
        self.rdo_logic.SetSelection(0)
        self.hbox_filter.Add(self.rdo_logic, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Add filter stuff to vbox_top
        self.vbox_top_left.Add(self.hbox_filter, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        # Add top components to hbox
        self.hbox_top.Add(self.vbox_top_left, 0, wx.EXPAND)


        ##########################
        # TOP RIGHT
        ##########################
        # Add warning text
        self.lbl_warning = wx.StaticText(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY,
                                         u"*** WARNING *** HELLO WORLD ",
                                         wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.lbl_warning.Wrap(-1)
        self.vbox_top_right.Add(self.lbl_warning, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Radio buttons for software choice
        rdo_choices = [u"App 1", u"App 2", u"App 3"]
        self.rdo_software = wx.RadioBox(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Select Software", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                        wx.DefaultSize, rdo_choices, 1, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
        self.rdo_software.SetSelection(0)
        self.vbox_top_right.Add(self.rdo_software, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Checkbox for archive
        self.cb_archive = wx.CheckBox(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Archive files before running", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                      wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.vbox_top_right.Add(self.cb_archive, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Checkbox for saving
        self.cb_save = wx.CheckBox(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Save files after running", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                   wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.vbox_top_right.Add(self.cb_save, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Folder selection label
        self.lbl_cases = wx.StaticText(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Select Folder With Cases", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                       wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.lbl_cases.Wrap(-1)
        self.vbox_top_right.Add(self.lbl_cases, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Add Folder selection
        self.hbox_folder = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.txt_cases = wx.TextCtrl(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.txt_cases.SetMinSize(wx.Size(400, -1))
        self.hbox_folder.Add(self.txt_cases, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Folder select button
        self.btn_cases = wx.Button(self.top_panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Case Folder", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.hbox_folder.Add(self.btn_cases, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Add to sizer
        self.vbox_top_right.Add(self.hbox_folder, 1, wx.SHAPED, 5)
        self.hbox_top.Add(self.vbox_top_right, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.vbox_main.Add(self.hbox_top, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        ####################################################
        # BOTTOM
        ####################################################

        self.bottom_box = wx.StaticBox(self.bottom_panel, label='Progress Output')
        self.hbox_output = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.bottom_box, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.txt_output = wx.TextCtrl(self.bottom_box, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                                      wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)


        # Put it all together
        self.vbox_main.Add(self.top_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.vbox_main.Add(self.bottom_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.top_panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.hbox_top)
        self.bottom_panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.hbox_output)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.vbox_main)
        self.Centre()
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    MainFrame = GUI(None, title='Batch Apply %s' % VERSION)
    app.SetTopWindow(MainFrame)
    MainFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here is a crude drawing of the GUI
[image: Crude drawing of GUI]

Here is what I am getting:
[image: Output]

Comment: Can you post a sketch of your panels & controls and the directions they can be (automatically) resized?

Comment: In the while, `sizer.Add(somecontrol, 0, wx.EXPAND)` will make the control not resizable in the direction of the sizer (due to the '0'), but resizable in the other direction (due to wx.EXPAND).

Comment: I have added a crude sketch as well as what I am getting when I run the code.  I have also changed the `proportion` flag to 1 when I add the `vbox_top_right` sizer to the `hbox_top` sizer and the top looks better, but still have a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main frame has only one child called `panel`. So, this **only child** of a frame (not of another kind of window) will fit it's parent's client area when it gets resized. Good. It would'nt be true in case of more than one child.

You have two more panels, as children of `panel`. This would be good if, for example, you want different background colors. If not, that's not necessary, but there's nothing wrong with these superfluous panels.

There are two different regions: top (not resizable in vertical direction) and bottom (resizable). This would require two sub-sizers of the 'main sizer' that handles the layout of the contents of `panel`. But you are using two panels for these regions, so better let's use a main sizer (I'll use `vbox_main`) for the layout inside `panel` of these two panels. The layout of the contents of a sub-panel will be handled by a sizer.

In the 'top' region there are also two different areas; so another two sub-sizers. Your design is correct.

`vbox_top_left` wants the controls it manages (children of `top_panel`) to fit in the available space. Because this is a *vertical* sizer we need:

1) A child can change vertical size: use `proportion=1`

2) A child can change horizontal size: use `wx.EXPAND` flag.

3) If would be good to add vertical resizable spacers between some controls.

Apply similar criteria for the controls size-handled by `vbox_top_right` (with children of `top_panel` too).

Bottom area is peculiar because you want a rectangle to be drawn around a label and a text control. For this, we need a special sizer: [StaticBoxSizer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.StaticBoxSizer.html). It's peculiar in the sense that the controls it handles are children not of a panel, but of the underlaying `wx.StaticBox`. See the upper docs link for an example and more explanations.

```
self.hbox_output = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL, self.bottom_panel)
self.hbox_output.Add(wx.StaticText(self.hbox_output.GetStaticBox(), ....), ...)
self.hbox_output.Add(wx.TextCtrl(self.hbox_output.GetStaticBox(), ....), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
```

To add children to this sizer follow the same criteria as for 'top' area. There's nothing distinct here.

Now, behaviours of the sizers (I skip other sub-sizers you use):

```
# No vertical nor horizontal expanding
# self.hbox_top.Add(self.vbox_top_left, 0, wx.EXPAND) <<== not what expected
self.hbox_top.Add(self.vbox_top_left, 0)

# Only horizontal expanding
# self.hbox_top.Add(self.vbox_top_right, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)  <<== not what expected
self.hbox_top.Add(self.vbox_top_right, 1, 0, 5)
```

The last job is to bind panels and sizers:

```
self.top_panel.SetSizer(self.hbox_top)
self.bottom_panel.SetSizer(self.hbox_output)

# Top panel expands only in horizontal
self.vbox_main.Add(self.top_panel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
# Bottom part expands in both directions
self.vbox_main.Add(self.bottom_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.vbox_main)
self.Centre()
self.Layout()
```

Using a single panel is easier. I've used your two sub-panels just to demostrate how it works: Main sizer handles sub-panels, each panel uses a sizer for its sizers that handle children.

Comment: Thanks Ripi2, I will take your thoughts here and work with them.  I originally had it all in one panel (no top or bottom sub-panels), but was thinking it might help with the issue I was having.  That is obviously not the case.